# Join multiple "Curve to Mesh" results into one singular connected mesh

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to build a tree generator using the "Shortest Edge Paths" Node. So far, I've gotten to the part where I have the tree as a union of curves where each curve goes from the root to a single leave ( technically from the other way around, leaf -> root ).

Now I want to transform these into a single mesh, so I thought:

"Curve To Mesh" > "Mesh Boolean: Union"

However this seems to crash Blender. After trying "Mesh to Volume" > "Volume to Mesh" or messing with the curve tilt, I could not get a satisfactory result.

What would be the best way to tackle this problem?

( These Meshes have, on purpose, "low" detail )
( for example, Realistically I would use a cross section circle with more then 4 vertices )
[image: Curve Structure]
[image: Resulting mesh]

[image]